# How to navigate between timer pages in Flutter while preserving AppBar and BottomBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, state-management, appbar

I'm developing a Flutter app with a timer feature. Currently, when the timer reaches zero, I want to automatically transition to a new page ("shortbreak.dart") while maintaining the overall app layout, including the AppBar and BottomBar.

**My Existing Structure:**

- **home_page_timer.dart:** Contains the primary timer and navigation logic.
- **startpomodoro.dart:** Defines the first-timer page.
- **shortbreak.dart:** Defines the second timer page.

**I have this design:**

[image]

**If time is over, I want to navigate to this page automatically**

[image]

**Code:**

**home_page_timer.dart**

```
class HomePageTimerUI extends StatelessWidget {
bool PomoRed = false;
bool ShortYellow = false;
bool LongBlue = false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 600,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            child: Scaffold(
                bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
                appBar: AppBar(
                  elevation: 1.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  bottom: PreferredSize(
                    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(55),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: SafeArea(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TabBar(
                                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Color(0xff3B3B3B), width: 4.0),
                                    insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 11.0)),
                                indicatorWeight: 15,
                                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                                labelColor: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    letterSpacing: 1.3,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xffD7D7D7),
                                tabs: [
                                  Tab(
                                    text: "POMODORO",
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.work_history, size: 40),
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    text: "SHORT BREAK",
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.ramen_dining, size: 40),
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    text: "LONG BREAK",
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.battery_charging_full_rounded,
                                        size: 40),
                                  ),
                                ])
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                body: TabBarView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: StartPomodoro(),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: ShortBreak(),
                    ),
                    Center(
                        child: LongBreak()
                    ),
                  ],
                ))));

  }
}
```

**startpomodoro.dart**

```
    class StartPomodoro extends StatefulWidget {
      const StartPomodoro({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<StartPomodoro> createState() => _StartPomodoroState ();
    }
    
    class _StartPomodoroState extends State<StartPomodoro>
        with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      List<bool> isSelected = [true, false];
      late Timer timer;
      late AnimationController controller;
    
      String get countText {
        Duration count = controller.duration! * controller.value;
        return controller.isDismissed
            ? '${controller.duration!.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'
            : '${count.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
      }
    
      double progress = 1.0;
      bool LongBreak = true;
    
      void notify() {
        if (countText == '00:00:00') {
          FlutterRingtonePlayer.playNotification();
      }
    }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 0),
        );
        controller.addListener(() {
          notify();
          if (controller.isAnimating) {
            setState(() {
              progress = controller.value;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              progress = 1.0;
              LongBreak = true;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: LongBreak? Color(0xffD94530) : Color(0xff6351c5),
          body: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (controller.isDismissed) {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => Container(
                    height:300,
                    child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                      initialTimerDuration: controller.duration!,
                      onTimerDurationChanged: (time) {
                        setState(() {
                          controller.duration = time;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
    
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: controller,
                builder: (context, child) {
                  return Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Color(0xffD94530),
                          height:
                          controller.value * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.742,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child:
                                Align(
                                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        countText,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 90.0,
                                          color: Color(0xffF2F2F2),),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                AnimatedBuilder(
                                    animation: controller,
                                    builder: (context, child) {
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                                      );
                                    }),
                                AnimatedBuilder(
                                    animation: controller,
                                    builder: (context, child) {
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                                        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                            backgroundColor: Color(0xffF2F2F2),
                                            onPressed:() {
                                              if (controller.isAnimating) {
                                                controller.stop();
                                                setState(() {
                                                  LongBreak = false;
                                                });
                                              } else {
                                                controller.reverse(
                                                    from: controller.value == 0 ? 1.0 : controller.value);
                                                setState(() {
                                                  LongBreak = false;
                                                });
                                              }
                                            },
                                            icon: Icon(
                                              controller.isAnimating ?
                                              Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                                              color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),),
                                            label: Text(
                                              controller.isAnimating ?  "PAUSE" : "PLAY",
                                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3B3B3B)),)),
                                      );
                                    }),
                                SizedBox(width: 20,),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**shortbreak.dart**

```
class ShortBreak extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShortBreak({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShortBreak> createState() => _ShortBreakState ();
}

class _ShortBreakState extends State<ShortBreak>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<bool> isSelected = [true, false];
  late Timer timer;
  late AnimationController controller;

  String get countText {
    Duration count = controller.duration! * controller.value;
    return controller.isDismissed
        ? '${controller.duration!.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'
        : '${count.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  double progress = 1.0;
  bool LongBreak = true;

  void notify() {
    if (countText == '00:00:00') {
      FlutterRingtonePlayer.playNotification();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 0),
    );
    controller.addListener(() {
      notify();
      if (controller.isAnimating) {
        setState(() {
          progress = controller.value;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          progress = 1.0;
          LongBreak = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: LongBreak? Color(0xff6351c5) : Color(0xffD94530),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (controller.isDismissed) {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => Container(
                height:300,
                child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                  initialTimerDuration: controller.duration!,
                  onTimerDurationChanged: (time) {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.duration = time;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        },

        child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: controller,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Color(0xff6351c5),
                      height:
                      controller.value * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.742,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child:
                            Align(
                              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    countText,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 90.0,
                                      color: Color(0xffF2F2F2),),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            AnimatedBuilder(
                                animation: controller,
                                builder: (context, child) {
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                                  );
                                }),
                            AnimatedBuilder(
                                animation: controller,
                                builder: (context, child) {
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                                    child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xffF2F2F2),
                                        onPressed:() {
                                          if (controller.isAnimating) {
                                            controller.stop();
                                            setState(() {
                                              LongBreak = false;
                                            });
                                          } else {
                                            controller.reverse(
                                                from: controller.value == 0 ? 1.0 : controller.value);
                                            setState(() {
                                              LongBreak = false;

                                            });
                                          }
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          controller.isAnimating ?
                                          Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                                          color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),),
                                        label: Text(
                                          controller.isAnimating ?  "PAUSE" : "PLAY",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3B3B3B)),)),
                                  );
                                }),
                            SizedBox(width: 20,),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**What I've Tried:**

I've used `Navigator.pushReplacement` to switch pages, but this removes my existing AppBar and BottomBar.

I tried this:

```
void notify() {
    if (countText == '00:00:00') {
      FlutterRingtonePlayer.playNotification();
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> 
 StartShortBreak()));
});
    }
  }
```

**Goal:**

How can I navigate between timer pages seamlessly within the same app structure, keeping the AppBar and BottomBar consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to navigate between tab view , not between actual Navigator

first, change your homeui to stateful widget with SigleTickerMixin,
instead of using DefaultTabController, make one. :

```
late TabController _tabController;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

and assign that tabcontroller to tabview and tabbar :

```
TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,

TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
```

use this

```
void notify() {
    if (countText == '00:00:00') {
      FlutterRingtonePlayer.playNotification();
//REMOVE THIS NAVIGATOR
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> 
 StartShortBreak()));
});
//Change to this :
_tabController.animateTo(1, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    }
  }
```

why index is 1, because you put ShortBreak in number 2 on your tabview childreen

Comment: Hello, I follow your steps but, unfortunately don't, work, when time is over don't change to "short break"

Comment: Hello again, it works but I had to edit this:  _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 1); and works with navigator as well

Answer (score 2):

In home page. Dart create a tab controller and assign it to the tab bar view. Then create a method to change index

```dart
void chageIndex(int index)
{
  _tabController.animateTo(index);
}
```

Then pass this method to promo screen

```dart
class StartPomodoro extends StatefulWidget {
final Function (index) changeIndex;
      const StartPomodoro({Key? key, required this.changeIndex}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<StartPomodoro> createState() => _StartPomodoroState ();
    }
```

You have to pass it like this

```dart
body: TabBarView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: StartPomodoro(changeIndex : changeIndex),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: ShortBreak(),
                    ),
                    Center(
                        child: LongBreak()
                    ),
                  ],
```

Then in startpromodoro in place of navigator. Push you can use

```dart
widget.changeIndex(1);
```

Comment: Hello, I follow your steps but, unfortunately don't, work, when time is over it throws me to "ShortBreak" but the app bars to the top and bottom don't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your condition put this when start the timer or whatever you want to do:

```dart
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
  Navigator.pop(context);
});
```

Comment: Hello, I follow your step but, unfortunately don't, work, when time is over the app turn to black screen

Comment: thats some route issue that u have u most know how to navigate between tow page without that proplem i think the proplem that u have ur using tow matireal page so when it's back to context found nothing